# Bootstrap 4.5 Footer Center Media Icons

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, footer

I created a footer in Bootstrap 4.5 and am having trouble centering the icons when the screen transitions down to mobile. The icons shift from horizontal to vertical. How do I keep the icons centered for Desktop and Mobile?

```
.template-footer {
 margin-top: 20px;
 padding: 2.5rem 0;
 color: #FFF;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #842B37;
 border-top: .05rem solid #e5e5e5;
 }
 .template-footer p:last-child {
 margin-bottom: 0;

 }
      
 footer a {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 14px;
 transition-duration: 0.2s;
 }
      
 .social {
 margin-bottom:20px;
 }

<footer class="template-footer">        
<div class="col-md-12"> 
<div class="row justify-content-md-center">
<div class="col col-lg-1 col-xs-2">
<a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" aria-label=""><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-2">
   <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" aria-label=""><i class="fa fa-skype fa-2x"></i></a>
</div>
<div class="col col-lg-1 col-xs-2">
  <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" aria-label=""><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-2x"></i></a>
</div>
  </div>    
  </div>
```

https://codepen.io/nick-kester/pen/mdPJgEO

Comment: Use inline list instead of row. This fix your problem.

Comment: You said you're using Bootstrap 4.5. In 4.5, classes like `.col-xs-*` is gone. That was why your icons were not centered in mobile view. Change them to `.col-*`: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/migration/#grid-system. I put this as a comment as I'm afraid someone will argue if I do put it as an answer :p

Comment: I updated codepen to include my solution. I added row justify-content-center to the outside div and added col-auto to the 3 media links.

Comment: this problem is done, right?

Comment: Yes, this problem has been resolved